# VB 2010 '.ctor' is not valid identifier

Tags: vb.net

So I'm in a VB.Net class and I am writing a program. Last night after going through all of my code and testing my program I get an error message. 
It happens when I try to view my designer and it's a screen that says " '.ctor is not a valid identifier" and it gives me an option to show a call stack. I'm new to VB.Net so I'm not entirely sure what that's showing me and it doesn't appear to be anything with what I coded.

Does any one know about this? Can you tell me where to look? I'm a little lost. I printed my code and don't see anything in my written code and I can run the program just fine.

It does say that fixing this will prevent possible data loss and if I ignore it then I get a messagebox that tells me I might lose all control (which is wierd, I mean I have not lost control yet even though I have drunk a lot of mountain dew and coffee today)

I found another post but it hasn't helped me so far.

I didn't see the need to paste all of my code only because I don't see this '.ctor' anywhere in the code and I'm just kinda curious where else I can look.

Okay so I just found something online that says I may have written this line of code incorrectly.

```
  Private Sub Pollys_Flooring_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Me.Load

    PineRadioButton.Checked = True

End Sub
```

My form is called Pollys_Flooring and then it says I should have _Load which I do. Am I doing that right?

The program is a flooring estimator so it gives the user an option to choose the type of wood they would like. Here is my code that handles the radio button.

```
 Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PineRadioButton.CheckedChanged, _
CedarRadioButton.CheckedChanged, OakRadioButton.CheckedChanged, PressBoardRadioButton.CheckedChanged

    Dim SelectedRadioButton As RadioButton

    SelectedRadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton)


    If PineRadioButton.Checked Then
        FlooringPriceDecimal = PineDecimal

    ElseIf CedarRadioButton.Checked Then
        FlooringPriceDecimal = CedarDecimal

    ElseIf OakRadioButton.Checked Then
        FlooringPriceDecimal = OakDecimal

    ElseIf PressBoardRadioButton.Checked Then
        FlooringPriceDecimal = PressboardDecimal

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try posting your constructor code.  The designer likes an empty constructor.

Comment: I just edited and added some code. Its definitely that code because I commented it out and now I'm not running into the issue I was having. Can you tell if I wrote it correctly? It matches what I have in my book so I must be missing osmething stupid.

Comment: Do you have code that handles the PineRadioButton CheckChanged event?  That would be the next place to look.

Comment: @LarsTech I just added the code to my question.

Comment: Doesn't tell me much unfortunately.  I assume FlooringPriceDecimal is a decimal type variable? Do you have a `Public Sub New()` code?  If so, show that.  By any chance, do you have a procedure called `Sub Pollys_Flooring()`?  I believe having a procedure the same name as the form could cause that error.

Comment: @LarsTech I found it! I actually had two lines for that Pollys_Flooring_Load so that is what caused it. I guess I didn't realize it was in my code (it's a little sloppy but I'm new) Anyway Thank you because you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on the Class Diagram and it said that slnFutureValue.frm did not exist.  So I allowed Visual Studio to remove it and then not only did my real .frm show, but also the '.ctor is not a valid identifier' error was gone!

So what appears to be happening is that VB could not find the contructor for the object slnFutureValue.frm, and so the error message '.ctor is not a valid identifier' which may be as a result from the way the reference to the constructor's name in the String was coded.